# How to show only indexes on mat-stepper?

Tags: angular, angular-material

`mat-stepper` for now shows an `edit` or `done` material icon if a step is `completed`. Is there way not to show icon, but only index?

Answer (score 0):

There's a hack that you can use, adding `stepControl` will do the magic. Not sure if it is the proper solution or not, but it worked for me.

Try this,

**.component.html**

```
<mat-step [stepControl]="doneFormGroup">
    <ng-template matStepLabel>Done</ng-template>
    <p>You are now done.</p>
    <div>
      <button mat-button matStepperPrevious>Back</button>
      <button mat-button (click)="stepper.reset()">Reset</button>
    </div>
</mat-step>
```

**.component.ts**

```
export class StepperVerticalExample implements OnInit {
  firstFormGroup: FormGroup;
  secondFormGroup: FormGroup;
  doneFormGroup: FormGroup;

  constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.firstFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      firstCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.secondFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      secondCtrl: ['', Validators.required]
    });
    this.doneFormGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
      doneControl: ['',Validators.required]
    })
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!!.. Happy Coding!!

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that. The problem is once your form control is valid, then the step becomes `completed` and after that `mat-stepper` adds an icon either `edit` or `done`. I decided just to mark all steps as `[completed]="false"`. This way `mat-stepper` will never show an icon, but only indexes. Pretty ugly, but what else we can do here. `mat-stepper` is one of the worst material components I've dealt so far.